# Resetting counter to 0 during a for loop for comparing string to a list of strings

Tags: python, list, for-loop, count, compare

I have a list of 90 strings and then an X string. In my code I am comparing x to each of the 90 strings and counting frequency of how many matches in each string in the list. This worked at first but then I realised its printing out the cumulative frequency. I changed my code so that the counter is inside my loop but I realise that now although count is resetting its not actually going through all the list? when I print the length of the list in the end rather than 90 results i'm getting 11? and im not sure why.

iv recreated below:

Comment: Your code is not valid: There's a missing `)` and `s` is undefined? How does the expected output look like?

Comment: @Timus I have updated now. In would like to print out the dictionary with matches and strings (k and v)

Comment: Are you aware that dictionary keys are unique: a dictionary like the one you have provided is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `Counter` object from `collections`

```
import collections
l = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c']
c = collections.Counter()
c.update(l)
print(c)
```

Results in this:

`Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are overwriting your dictionary. When you come across a string with the same number of matches as previous string, you set `results[matches]` to that string, thus erasing the previous string stored there. The length of `result` is thus the length of the number of unique numbers of matches. I can’t propose a fix as it is not entirely clear what you are trying to implement here.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out!! would like a dictionary of all the strings in my list and a counter for how alike it is to string x. so I am comparing each one to it and then calculating matches. how do I stop the dictionary over writing?

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you want to achieve. Here are a couple of options: With

```py
words = [
    'ABCD', 'ABBB', 'ACCC', 'AACC', 'ACDA', 'AACC', 'ABBB', 'ACCC',
    'AGGG', 'ABBC', 'BBBA', 'BCCD', 'ABBE', 'ABBE', 'ACDE', 'ACCC'
]
base = 'ACEC'
```

this

```py
results = [(sum(a == b for a, b in zip(base, word)), word) for word in words]
```

results in

```py
[(1, 'ABCD'), (1, 'ABBB'), (3, 'ACCC'), (2, 'AACC'), (2, 'ACDA'), (2, 'AACC'),
 (1, 'ABBB'), (3, 'ACCC'), (1, 'AGGG'), (2, 'ABBC'), (0, 'BBBA'), (1, 'BCCD'),
 (1, 'ABBE'), (1, 'ABBE'), (2, 'ACDE'), (3, 'ACCC')]
```

and this

```py
results = {word: sum(a == b for a, b in zip(base, word)) for word in words}
```

results in

```py
{'ABCD': 1, 'ABBB': 1, 'ACCC': 3, 'AACC': 2, 'ACDA': 2, 'AGGG': 1,
 'ABBC': 2, 'BBBA': 0, 'BCCD': 1, 'ABBE': 1,'ACDE': 2}
```

and this

```py
results = {}
for word in words:
    results.setdefault(sum(a == b for a, b in zip(base, word)), []).append(word)
```

results in

```py
{0: ['BBBA'],
 1: ['ABCD', 'ABBB', 'ABBB', 'AGGG', 'BCCD', 'ABBE', 'ABBE'],
 2: ['AACC', 'ACDA', 'AACC', 'ABBC', 'ACDE'],
 3: ['ACCC', 'ACCC', 'ACCC']}
```

Comment: Thank ou ver much for this, I believe the second one is what im looking for. it doesn't over write whilst adding to the dictionary right?

Comment: @기리보이외국인ARMY It does override, but with the same value:  keys are unique, unlike in the other two versions, the second one only stores the result for a `word` once (the input contains words that occur multiple times, e.g. `'ACCC'`).